Am I allowed to publicly reshare some JSON file containing SE data created after the introduction of the new data dump process?
I ran across some JSON (magnet link) containing SE data that was created after the introduction of the new data dump process. Am I allowed to publicly reshare it (e.g., on https://archive.org), or will SE punish me (e.g., suspension, lawsuit, stop giving access to dumps, etc.) if I do so?

Philippe already recognized that right:

Maxwell175 Commented Jul 12 at
23:15:
@Philippe, you do realize that there is nothing you can do to prevent
your community from simply maintaining the archive.org mirror for you?
I guarantee that the moment the dumps are made available there will be
dozens of people immediately downloading them and mirroring them to
archive.org. This whole worthless exercise is just a waste of
development time.



Philippe [Staff] Commented Jul 12 at
23:53:
@Maxwell175, I do, yes. My hope is that over time, they see that
there's no need, but that will take time, I understand. (mirror)

That said, I don't think company can do anything about it legally (Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer) considering the CC-By-SA license. Their "infamous checkbox agreement" also doesn't say anything about redistribution in general (just talks about LLM training related purposes). As it has been phrased before by others, and in my opinion, this whole futile charade is nothing but a gaslighting attempt and a scarecrow for AI companies so they pay Stack Overflow some money.

perfect, great to hear!

@Frank the button has no legal significance. The content is under the CC license - you could redistribute it even if you bought the dump or as a book from the company. All the checkbox does is implementing a threat: the company is letting you know that they have gone back on their words about being a repository of knowledge and that they no longer live to the values Jeff had in mind when creating this site. They are treating people to stop providing them the content in a ready format should they dare to compete in the same business field they are already trying to monetize: selling our data.

@SPArcheon-onstrike my OCD wants me to mod flag your comment to edit "treating" to "threatening". Auto-correct is a demon.
